# Why the result is not correct using python to know the line numbers of a file

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, line-numbers

I want to know the line numbers of a certain file
Following is the code

But the result is not correct:The true file line number == Console result number + 1

is the problem in "open().readlines()" ?

if there are contents in the last line, the result is correct

```
import os
import os.path

absPath = os.curdir

while True:  
    print '\nplease select the file you want to know the line nums:'
    print os.listdir(absPath)    

    fileName = raw_input()

    absFilePath = absPath + '//' + fileName
    if os.path.isfile(absFilePath):
        count = len(open(absFilePath).readlines())
        print 'the ' + fileName + ' file line nums is>>>' + str(count) + '>>>'
    else:
        print 'Please check the fileName or the input is not a file'
```

Comment: Can you show this file? Also, try to post a minimal example which reproduces this result.

Comment: I tried your code and it returned the same value as wc -l

How are you trying to verify your code?

Comment: I would just use `len(open('file.txt').read().splitlines())`

Comment: Does the file you're checking end with an newline? If so, should the empty last line be counted or not?

Comment: I find the reason:the notepad++ line num(left side) shows 6,but open().readlines() return list ['aaa\n','bbb\n','ccc\n','\n','\n'] '\n' will add a new line num,but not add a list num

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason:
the notepad++ line num(left side) shows 6,
but open().readlines() return list ['aaa\n','bbb\n','ccc\n','\n','\n']

'\n' will add a new line num in editor,but not add a list num

So if the last line is like 'bbb',the script is correct
if the last is like '\n' ,'\n',the line num must add 1

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `readlines()` here, as it unnecessarily loads the whole file into memory. The following snippet is more memory-friendly:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    line_count = sum(1 for line in f)
```